# Using CountIf in excel with row() as the 2nd range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

Is it possible to have a function in Excel where the second range is the current row the user is current at?  For example, if column A has customer numbers then can a user have column B be the current count of rows that have the same customer number?  Something like `=countif(A1:Row(), Row())`.  So, if the user were on B14 then the function would be `=countif(A1:A14, A14)`.

I'd rather not use VBA and I'm new to functions in Excel.  My apologies if it's a simple answer.  I swear that I did search for an answer before firing off this question.

Comment: Although I posted an answer, I might be misunderstanding your question, I just based it in your example. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes. Use *INDIRECT* function. Something like:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("A1:A"&Row()), INDIRECT("A"&Row()))
```

Comment: That was the exact thing I was looking for.  It works like a charm.  Thank you L42.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something else rather than taking the current row you could have a **drop-down list** with all the ids. The cell remains the same but you will be able to select the number that you want from the list and use it to count.

Have a look here and tell me if you need more help:
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-to-add-a-drop-down-list-to-an-excel-cell/

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET($A$1,0,0,ROW()),A:A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Better than using the "fully" volatile OFFSET and INDIRECT set-ups is to use one with INDEX, which, in this construction, is merely volatile "at workbook open".

Also, if you are looking for a formula which can be copied to other cells such that the row referenced is always that in which the formula resides, it is much better to use a construction with ROWS rather than ROW, since the latter is affected by row insertions within the range whereas the former is not. Hence, the formula placed in row 14 would be:

=COUNTIF(A1:INDEX(A:A,ROWS($1:14)),INDEX(A:A,ROWS($1:14)))

Regards

Comment: Good call.  Even better would be `=COUNTIF($A$1:INDEX(A:A,ROW()),A:A)`

Comment: You're using the entirety of column A as the criteria value?? And I still think that the use of unqualified ROW() constructions is one of the most overused, though misunderstood, features of proposed solutions around the various Excel forums on the internet.

Comment: _You're using the entirety of column A ... as the criteria value_. Yes I am.  Used like this it's actually an intersection opertor, and returns the intersection of column A and the row the Formula is on.  As to `Row()`, it returns the row number of the row the formula is on, exactly what is required in this case.  How is that "overuse"?